# Открытие нового окна

Tags: php, html

Всем удачного дня!
В одном из php скриптов есть такой момент:

```
header("Location: 123.php");
```

Всё прекрасно работает: прыжок происходит, но возникла необходимость открытия 123.php в новом окне, как такое реализовать?

Comment: `echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.open("123.php");</script>';` - только так. Если не секрет, можно узнать логику работы вашего скрипта?

Comment: Логика проста. )) Есть форма - она заполняется пользователем, после нажатия кнопки отправить пользователь попадает на страницу с результатами обработки введёных им данных, а требуется, чтобы он оставался на странице с формой, а результат обработки открывался в отдельном окне или вкладке...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У формы пропишите `target="_blank"` - и все. =)

Comment: Сперва я в эту сторону и смотрел,это то что нужно,но проблема в том, что в таком случае у меня выводиться будет вся страничка с формой,а потом результат обработки,а нужен только результат.Хотя завтра поэксперементирую,а то сейчас голова совсем не варит))

Comment: Собственно голова заработала,сделал))Спасибо)Преобразуйте пожалуйста в ответ комментарий по поводу target,чтобы его можно было принять.

Answer (score 0):

Это возможно только на javascript.

[Window open() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

> The open() method opens a new browser window.

Comment: Про этот метод я знаю...А неужели по другому никак?

Comment: Можно еще для ссылки выставлять свойство target="_blank", тогда при клике по ней будет открываться новое окно. По другому, к сожалению (или скорее к счастью), никак.